# How to automatically enable the ELB Cipher policy specified in the Cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb, aws-security-hub

Policies that I specified under Cloudformation ELB Policies attribute is not enabled after deployment. I had to enable it manually util then the old default Policy was in effect. How to automatically enable the ELB Cipher policy specified in the Cloudformation ?

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-elb-policy.html

```
Policies:
    - PolicyName: My-SSLNegotiation-Policy
      PolicyType: SSLNegotiationPolicyType
      Attributes:
      - Name: Reference-Security-Policy
        Value: ELBSecurityPolicy-TLS-1-2-2017-01
```

On the AWS Console it was still showing the predefined policy as `ELBSecurityPolicy-2016-08` which is the default policy

Then I had to manually enable it using the cli below then it showed predefined policy as `ELBSecurityPolicy-TLS-1-2-2017-01`

```
aws elb set-load-balancer-policies-of-listener --load-balancer-name auhuman-ELB-qwertyuiop --load-balancer-port 443 --policy-names Auhuman-ELBSecurityPolicy-TLS-1-2-2017-01 --region us-east-1
```

Comment: As stated in the documentation: _To associate policies with a listener, use the PolicyNames property for the listener._ Did you associate the policy with the listener in your CF template?

Comment: Specifying the PolicyNames (My-SSLNegotiation-Policy) in my listener worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This style of policy definition is associated with the classic EC2 load balancer. If at all possible, you should use a [V2 application load balancer instead](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-elasticloadbalancingv2-loadbalancer.html). Really the only use case for a classic ELB is if you have classic EC2 instances not in a VPC...and you should be thinking about migration strategy for those.

Assuming you can use a V2 ALB, you can use the `SslPolicy` property on the listener to declare your policy, for example:

```
LoadBalancerSecureListener:
  Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::Listener
  Properties:
    LoadBalancerArn: !Ref LoadBalancer
    Protocol: HTTPS
    Port: 443
    Certificates:
      - CertificateArn: !Ref ACSCertificate
    SslPolicy: ELBSecurityPolicy-TLS-1-2-2017-01
    DefaultActions:
      - Type: forward
        TargetGroupArn: !Ref DefaultTargetGroup
```

Of course you'll need to substitute appropriate references for your situation.

If you absolutely have to use a classic ELB, then you need to associate the policy name with the listener by adding the `PolicyNames` property to the listener config, as in:

```
 Loadbal:
    Type: 'AWS::ElasticLoadBalancing::LoadBalancer'
    Properties:
      Subnets:
        - !Ref subnet1
        - !Ref subnet2
      Listeners:
        - InstancePort: 80
          LoadBalancerPort: 443
          Protocol: HTTPS
          SSLCertificateId: >-
            !Ref ACSCertificate
          PolicyNames:
            - My-SSLNegotiation-Policy
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: My-SSLNegotiation-Policy
          PolicyType: SSLNegotiationPolicyType
          Attributes:
            - Name: Reference-Security-Policy
              Value: ELBSecurityPolicy-TLS-1-2-2017-01
```